# LINQ Exists or Any predicates

Tags: c#, linq

I have a DB that registers some Activities performed by Patients, each Patient can have many or none Activities per day.

**Classes are:**

```cs
public class Patient {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Activity {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string ActivityName { get; set; }
    public int Patient_ID { get; set; }
}

// Load all relevant data from DB
public List<Patient> patientsAll = LoadPatientsAll();
public List<Activity> activitiesAll = LoadActivitiesAll();

// This list should only contain Patients,
// who had any record in activitiesAll a certain day
public List<Patient> patientsRelevant;
```

How can I select a `List<Patient>` of `DISTINCT` Patients who had any registered Activity per day (into patientsRelevant variable)?

Comment: What kind of ORM are you using? And what's the code for the `LoadXXXXAll()` methods?

Comment: There are a couple of things you can do to make your life easier. First, add an Activities property to your Patient class of type List<Activity> and tell it to use the Patient_ID as the foreign key.

Then we can show you a pretty clean Linq query.

Comment: show us your work please.  what have you tried?

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi : I can't use entities or 'include'. Can't use SQL View either. Using - what is it called, 'Passthrough Query'? - direct SELECT statement on DB

Comment: @BrettCaswell I was trying Exists and Any predicates and have nothing reasonable to show. Answer below gave me the understanding that I should've used select/join instead

Comment: @41686d6564 As far as I can tell, its SQLite with some 3rd party driver and manually created classes. LoadPatientsAll() simply loads all Patients from DB. LoadActivitiesAll() - all Activities for today.

Comment: Yeah an inner join is the thing to use. Along with a WHERE clause for the date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your given input, try this:

```
var query =
from patient in patientsAll
join activity in activitiesAll.Where(x=> x.CreateDate == DATEREQUIRED)
on patient.ID equals activity.Patient_ID
select patient;

var patients = query.Distinct();
```

The normal Linq join is an inner join, and therefore would only return records from patient where there is a corresponding record in activity.